# jHipster does not add default fields like last_modified_by

Tags: jhipster

I'm using jHipster 4.14.4 . When using the generator to generate entities, it seems it does not generate the default fields like last_modified_by and last_modified_by, neither in the XML files for the DB or the class files. Am I wrong to assume these are included by default? I need these to be able to sync with an offline app I'm building.

Comment: They are not included by default

Comment: Have you tried this module https://github.com/hipster-labs/generator-jhipster-entity-audit ? You may want to test compatibility with 4.14.4

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be what I needed!